# Anime from 2008-2012 involving furry characters and a watermelon shaped monster

Tags: story-identification, anime, cgi

#### Chronology & other Information

I went to Fry's Electronics at some point between 2008 and 2012 and I saw this CGI anime thing on one of the TVs.

#### Plot points

What I remember is that:

1. It was CGI (a cutscene or a movie of some kind) and there were several characters running from this monster.
2. At least one character had furry ears (maybe more), they were all of thin build, there was at least one female in the group (who may also have furry ears).
3. I want to say the monster was watermelon-shaped. This creature may have been a shade of green.
4. It was not cartoon-like at all.
5. The "walkway" that they were in might be a brick-type, somewhat enclosed like a European city. Not quite an alleyway, but definitely bigger than one. Could be sci-fi, it had some decent CGI (Final Fantasy level (at least 2006 quality).

Help is much appreciated. Ask for clarification and I will describe as best I can.

Comment: Given the time period, the furry ears, and the fact that you describe it as having Final Fantasy-like graphics, is it possible that this was a trailer for Final Fantasy 14, the MMO game originally released in 2010? I haven't reviewed the trailers to see if there's a matching scene with a monster, but check out [the cat-eared Miqo'te species](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Miqo'te#Gallery) from FF14 and see if that matches the characters you're thinking of.

Comment: They do fight a malboro, a plant monster with a somewhat watermelon-shaped head, in [one of the FF14 trailers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XbxPsWFyU8), but the fight doesn't take place in a city.

Comment: @recognizer I did check out FF14 in my searches (and the Miqo'te) but it didn't match. The characters in the scene I saw were of similar height. I watched the trailer, but it's not the same. The characters were definitely running away from the monster as it chased them. I don't quite recall, but it may (the monster) have only two legs and I want to say that it wobbled from side to side as it ran.

Comment: After watching that trailer though, I can say it's quality did not pass that at all. Probably lower.